# Possibilities of AngularFire, sum of values entered by users, obtaining sum at main site with angular?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Suppose we want to develop a website. Key features:

1. home page (access for all) the main element on the page is the
   sum of payments
2. registration and login page - mail address and password, account activation
3. the payment will be declared by the registered and logged in users through the form and a checkbox, when the checkbox is selected data should be uploaded to the server and saved if "pass verification" for example, do not exceed $ 10, each user in one day can only declare one payment
4. after possitive verification the sum from "number 1 above" is updated
5. additional features - user notification: when the last payment hasn't been made for more than six months, or if the total sum exceeds a certain level eg $ 1,000...

Is it possible that the whole solution would be based on angularfire? In particular:

- the sum of payments - on main site the information about
  the sum avaible for all visitors, so each time somebody visits the website
  we will have to send request to Firebase to get all the records and
  add the payments to finally show the sum on web site? With Angular we  can do that?
- Firebase enables queries/limits: e.g. last 20, but to get the whole amount you need to have knowledge of the previous value - in this case, increase in payments and visits will result in sending large amounts of data client side vs firebase - whether and how it can be optimized?
- suppose that the activation of user account will require small payment
  (paypal/transfer) is it possible to set account active when the
  payment is done?

Comment: You can certainly use AngularFire to build the app but you'll have to carefully think about how to structure your data in Firebase to implement this. This blog post has some useful information on how you can denormalize your data: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html. To implement counters you can use the transaction primitive offered by Firebase to keep a global sum.

Comment: Where can I learn about transaction primitive offered by Firebase?

Comment: https://www.firebase.com/docs/transactions.html